# Trying to contour a CSV file in QGIS

Tags: csv, contour, qgis

I have rainfall data which I have imported as a csv file.  It's 185 lines like this:

```
Name, Longitude, Latitude, Elevation, TotalPrecipitation
BURLINGTON, -72.932, 41.794, 505, M
BAKERSVILLE, -73.008, 41.842, 686, 42.40
BARKHAMSTED, -72.964, 41.921, 710, M
NORFOLK 2 SW, -73.221, 41.973, 1340, 44.22
```

Looking at the layer properties the latitude and longitude are brought in as "double" but the rainfall amounts come in as "text" so I can't contour them.

How can I get beyond this point and where do I go to do the contouring?  Do I go to Vector:Contour?  Will it understand M is missing data or will the Ms still exist if this is converted to "double?"

I'm a little confused.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would start by deleting all those 'M's in the orginal CSV, then reimport. If there are no other surpises, then the TotalPrecipitation column should come in as double.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have the idea of help.

Since you have the sort of points located randomly across some area you could do as follows:

1. Load CSV to your QGIS in order to set the point layer with an attribute table including your most important value, which is **Total Precipitation**. Let's call it the `TEST` layer
2. **Processing Toolbox -> TIN Interpolation ->** Select the `TEST` layer. As an Interpolation attribute choose "Total precipitation". Use the green "**+**" symbol for adding this selection. Don't forget about the **Extent** option, where you could define the bounds of your interpolation. Preferably I wouldn't exceed the layer I am working on. **Output raster size** is also important - avoid a small number of rows. Put them about 10 optionally in order to make your interpolation efficient.
   [image]
   https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html
3. **Main bar -> Raster -> Extraction -> Contour**
   [image]
   In the input layer select `TEST`, Interval contours between lines can be 10 (10mm in your case), **Attribute name** - put **PRECIPITATION** -> click Run
4. Your precipitation lines are ready! Now, you can **Right-Click -> Properties -> Symbology (change color) or _>Labels (provide labels based on your attribute column Total Precipitation)**.